# Requested tensor connection from unknown node: "dense_5_target:0"

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, anomaly-detection, one-class-classification

I'm faced this error when I running this [code](https://github.com/cerlymarco/MEDIUM_NoteBook/blob/master/OneClass_NeuralNetwork/OneClass_NeuralNetwork.ipynb) in Google colab.

The error is:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-67951c7b20d5> in <module>()
     22 
     23 model3 = get_model3()
---> 24 model3.fit(wrap_generator3(train_generator3), steps_per_epoch=train_generator3.samples/train_generator3.batch_size, epochs=20)
     25 #model3.fit_generator(generator=train_generator3, steps_per_epoch=train_generator3.samples/train_generator3.batch_size, epochs=20)

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, session, callable_options)
   1468       try:
   1469         self._handle = tf_session.TF_SessionMakeCallable(
-> 1470             session._session, options_ptr)
   1471       finally:
   1472         tf_session.TF_DeleteBuffer(options_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: Requested tensor connection from unknown node: "dense_8_target:0".
```

How I solve this problem?
Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: This code does not show any error to me when I ran the same code in `Google colab` with `TensorFlow 2.7`. Please let me know which `TensorFlow` version are you using?